# AUTOCOMPLETE EDITTEXT

Tags: java, android

I have an edittext and a recyclerview. I want anytime a user enters character "@" as the first character of a new word in edittext, the recyclerview pops up just above the edittext. If the user continues to type after character "@", we are supposed to filter through the recyclerview items to match whatever the user has typed to the items in recyclerview.
In a nutshell, I want to implement something like the name suggestions in whatsapp group chats once you enter character "@", or in twitter.
So far, I've been able to show the recyclerview but only if "@" is the first character in edit text but if it is in the second word eg hallo @w.. the recyclerview wont show, please help. Also I need to hide the recyclerview if the user backspaces the "@", or deletes it. Thirdly, how to filter through the shown recyclerview by getting only the text that the user has entered after character "@".
 Please help, any assistance with some show of code will be of great help. Here is what I've tried so far.

```
   InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence s, int start, int end, Spanned spanned, int i2, int i3) {

            if (s.toString().contains("@")){


                foods.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //foods is the recyclerview

                userMessageInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int i2) {
                        //to filter through the recyclerview to match with whatever user has typed after character "@"
                        if (!s.toString().contains(" ")){

                            List<FoodObject> mlist = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (FoodObject object: allfoodList){   //allfoodlist is food arraylist passed to food adapter
                                String name = object.getName().trim().toLowerCase();
                                if (name.contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())){
                                    mlist.add(object);
                                }
                                foodadapter.searchFood(mlist); //foodadapter is the rv adapter
                            }

                        } else {
                            foods.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                });

            }
            else {
                Log.d("showit", "false");
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    userInput.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});  //userinput is the edittext field

//method in rv adapter to  search food
 public void searchFood(List<FoodObject> searchList){
    foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    foodList.addAll(searchList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it work you need to create a Adapter class. Let's suppose that you have a model class named User;

```
public class TextUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
private List<User> users;

public TextUserAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<User> userList) {
    super(context, 0, userList);
    users = new ArrayList<>(userList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return userFilter;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.textview_adapter_user, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtUsername = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);

    User user = getItem(position);

    if (convertView != null){
        txtUsername.setText(user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname()));
    }

    return convertView;
}

private Filter userFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        List<User> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

        if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0){
            suggestions.addAll(users);
        } else {
            String filterPattern = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (User user : users){
                if (user.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    suggestions.add(user);
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = suggestions;
        results.count = suggestions.size();

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        clear();
        addAll((List) filterResults.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        User user = (User) resultValue;
        return user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname();
    }
};
```

}

And in your activity or wherever your autoCompleteTextView is, you should add these codes

```
autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().contains("@")){
                TextUserAdapter textUserAdapter = new TextUserAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Your user list);
                autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(textUserAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Then you should add this under

```
    final ArrayList<User> userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            User user = (User) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            autoCompleteTextView.setText(autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString() + user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.cfsuman.kotlinexamples

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize a new array with elements
        val colors = arrayOf(
                "Red","Green","Blue","Maroon","Magenta",
                "Gold","GreenYellow"
        )


        // Initialize a new array adapter object
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, // Context
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, // Layout
                colors // Array
        )


        // Set the AutoCompleteTextView adapter
        auto_complete_text_view.setAdapter(adapter)


        // Auto complete threshold
        // The minimum number of characters to type to show the drop down
        auto_complete_text_view.threshold = 1


        // Set an item click listener for auto complete text view
        auto_complete_text_view.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
            parent,view,position,id->
            val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            // Display the clicked item using toast
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Selected : $selectedItem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


        // Set a dismiss listener for auto complete text view
        auto_complete_text_view.setOnDismissListener {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Suggestion closed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


        // Set a click listener for root layout
        root_layout.setOnClickListener{
            val text = auto_complete_text_view.text
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Inputted : $text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


        // Set a focus change listener for auto complete text view
        auto_complete_text_view.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener{
            view, b ->
            if(b){
                // Display the suggestion dropdown on focus
                auto_complete_text_view.showDropDown()
            }
        }
   }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#d7ded7"
    >
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_complete_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response Sir. Could you rewrite this in java kindly?

Comment: It is in Kotlin. You can convert it to Java.

Comment: Alright thank you. But I really wanted to maintain the edittext field as there are textwatchers cast to it that i dont want to lose